# Constructors and how they are utilized

Tags: java, parameters, constructor, default

I'm reading through my programming text and I have what I feel is a pretty logical question concerning constructors.

For example if I have the code:

```
public class Ship{
   String name;
   int position;

   public Ship(int position){
      this.position = position;
   }
   public Ship(String name){
      this.name = name;
   }
   public Ship(){
      name = "Titanic";
      position = 0;
   }
}
```

So if I have my jargon correct the `Ship()` is the default constructor. Whereas the constructors with parameters are the initialization constructors.

Now that is the background...here is my question! When I used one of the constructors that contain an argument, what happens to the field that is being utilized ( in this example the other field ). For example when I call `Ship(5)` what is the value of the `name` data field? Does it adopt the value of the default, or just the default for the data type?

Does this mean I have to set a value for the other field if I call this single argument constructor?

Comment: Why does the "default constructor" have a lowercase name, and why are the constructors outside of the class?

Comment: -1 Make sure to post compiling code (unless the question is about why code doesn't compile).

Comment: My apologies, I wrote this quickly just to explain the question easier = ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any instance variables that you don't initialize are given default values by Java.  Primitive types get the value `0`, and reference types are `null`.

You don't have to initialize the values, but for clarity, it's best to explicitly initialize all values.

Comment: So I suppose the best practice is then to give the instance variable values from the get go... i.e String name ="battleship." If that is the case how would the default constructor operate? Would it just be public ship(){ no code block b/c default values are already used }

Answer (score 3):

The field gets the default field value: 0 for numbers, null for objects. You will have to set the value of the other field in the one-argument constructor if the default is not what you want.